idiomatic speech and sense of rhythm
I have a question concerning the passage below: it describes the narrator reading her friend’s news feed on Facebook. Could you please tell me if ‘hugging two beauties (...) around the waist, ...’ is idiomatic enough or if it's better to replace it with
'flanked by two beauties (...), ...'?
[please notice that because it's the narrator's point of view,'beauties' may and should sound a bit patronizing and sexist]

…I opened Facebook and clicked on my friend’s news feed. It gave me
quite a predictable set of selfies: Petrova, hugging two beauties
(with somewhat ostrich faces) around the waist, appearing at a
press-conference in a spectacular black jacket, climbing the stairs
towards the marble Nike of Samothrace at the Louvre…


Sorry but asking if something "reads well" or has any errors isn't allowed here. The purpose of the site is to answer specific questions not to proof-read everything everybody writes. I'd guess "hugging two beauties around the waist" is OK but you should say why you are worried - is it "the waist" vs "their waist" vs "their waists"? (There are similar questions here you could look at, maybe about other body parts.) Or "beauties" is a bit patronizing or sexist, and maybe isn't the ideal word, and you might mean something else than "hugging" depending on how exactly they are holding each other.

Not sure hugging is the right verb since a hug usually takes two arms.

"flanked by" is often used for such scenarios.

Thank you both very much for your comments, and I'm sorry for not being specific enough. I'm very new to the forum, I need a little more time to understand how things work here. I'll edit the post and will be more specific in the future. Your comments helped me a lot. Thank you.

One arm around each beauty is the image, It's fine.

If this is "creative writing", it's up to you.  "Hugging" means putting arms around someone (for example around their waist), usually as a form of affection.  "Flanked by" just means "next to" with the connotation that the two "beauties" are giving some kind of support (for example having two "beauties" might be a way for a man to show wealth and power)
The meanings are different, and it is up to you what you want to describe.
